# Best way to enable writing on a Linux server with PHP

Tags: php, permissions, chmod

I have a CMS which i made with PHP and i want to add some self updating features to it.

A self updating system can be a complex and tedious thing, i know that, but that's a whole different story. The bottom line is is that i end up creating new PHP files, editting existing ones with new code and probably deleting some PHP files when an update happends.

I know how to read, write and delete files in PHP, but this almost always gives me problems on a Linux server when i don't `chmod` the folder with an FTP client first to `0777`.

I also know PHP has `chmod` and `chown` functions. But most of the times these functions **don't** work for me either. Mainly because all the PHP files are uploaded through FTP which gives the rights to write to files and folders to the FTP group (or something like that).

I also have a Wordpress blog installed on a Linux server, but for some reason this Wordpress site has no trouble updating itself. I assume it does the same things i said; create, update and delete certain files. But none of the Wordpress sites i ever worked with complained that it couldn't update itself because of the folder/file permissions.

So i'm guessing Wordpress uses a smart way to change folder permissions when needed. I just couldn't figure out how.

So basically my question is, what is the best way to give PHP permissions to chmod files and folders on a Linux system? How does a system like Wordpress handle this?

Comment: files written by ftp will be done as whatever user the ftp server is running as. WP can update itself because it'll be running within Apache and generally files in a site are owned by apache anyways. You can try forcing group ownership by making the relevant directories `sgid`, e.g. `chmod 2775 writable_dir` and then using only that particular group for stuff.

Comment: If your problems are _permissions on a Linux server_, then why not start to deal with setting permissions right in an environment?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the folder to 0777 which would give PHP the capability to create files inside of it. You can also chown the folder to www-data or whatever your copy of PHP runs as...

Comment: As you probably know setting folders to 0777 isn't a very good thing... Next problem is `chown` you usually can't chown on a shared host. And even if you can you need a way to figure out what PHP runs as. Because that can differen on other systems.

Comment: You never specified you were on a shared host. Secondly I don't appreciate your down vote... I was only trying to help. If the solution doesn't work for you ask for another. Wordpress requires the folder to be set to 777 and so does pretty much every other CMS.

Comment: I know, but you posted what i basically said. I know i can change the permissions to 777, but that seems like a bad idea. And i was under the impression that Wordpress and others don't do that. But it seems like you're in the right direction though. The minimum permissions seems to be 766 which need to be set manually. On one of my servers ` 755` seems to be enough. Sorry about the downvote though, seems you were in the right direction. I'll just accept this as an answer.